# How do I get the key values from $_POST?

Tags: php, arrays

```
echo $_POST["name"]; //returns the value a user typed into the "name" field
```

I would like to be able to also return the text of the key. In this example, I want to return the text "name". Can I do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check out the array_keys() function assuming this is PHP.

https://www.php.net/array_keys

Answer (score 37):

$_POST is just a normal associative array so you can also loop over the entire thing like this:

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
{
  echo "$key=$value";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

@Tim: there was a `)` missing. so it should be:

```
while( list( $field, $value ) = each( $_POST )) {
   echo "<p>" . $field . " = " . $value . "</p>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
while( list( $field, $value ) = each( $_POST )) {
   echo "<p>" . $field . " = " . $value . "</p>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array_keys($_POST)
```

[Manual](http://de.php.net/array_keys)

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($_POST as $rvar)
{
 $rvarkey=key($_POST)
 $$rvarkey=mysql_real_escape_string($rvar);
}

it creates variables having the name of the request parameters which is pretty awesome.
```