# Checking variable is in URL then defining

Tags: php, http

I'm trying to do a simple function here, but it's not working.

I want to check if the variable is indeed in the URL, and if it is I want to define a variable with it.

```
if(isset($_GET['ref'])){
$ref = $_GET['ref'];
}
```

Could someone point out the errors?

Comment: Everything seems fine. What's the problem ?

Comment: You will have to specify what you mean by not working, if an error message exists you will have to show us that, otherwise we cannot help much.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably that isset only checks if the variable has been declared. That variable could still be empty. so this will set $ref even when $_GET['ref'] = ""; Try this instead:

```
if(isset($_GET['ref'])){
    if(!empty($_GET['ref'])))
    {
        $ref = $_GET['ref'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Get and Post variables are accessible to you as Arrays.  I would loop over the array and treat it as a Key/Value pair.  This will give you the ability to do what ever you would like with the key and the value.

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
{
  echo "$key=$value";
}
```

See this previous Stack Overflow thread. 
[How do I get the key values from $_POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183914/how-do-i-get-the-key-values-from-post)