# Handling inputs fields by number

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery

I have 10 inputs fields that are optional to fill out by the user and are dynamically added through jQuery upon clicking "Add another field". They are named like this:

```
<input name="custom_0" type="text" placeholder="Fill this out...">
<input name="custom_1" type="text" placeholder="Fill this out...">
<input name="custom_2" type="text" placeholder="Fill this out...">
...
<input name="custom_9" type="text" placeholder="Fill this out...">
```

I then use jQuery Ajax to serialize them and send it to a PHP for verification:

```
$(document).on("submit", "form", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/form_handler.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Here's the PHP I have right now. It contains a loop that loops 10 times and returns an error if a field isn't set:

```
<?php

    $errors = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        if(isset($_POST["custom_$i"])) {
            // input is set, continue verification code...
        } else {
            $errors["custom_$i"] = "ERROR!";
        }
    }

    // code to echo back errors

?>
```

The problem I have right now is that if the user has only filled out 2 of the 10 inputs, it will still return an error for inputs 3-10 even though those inputs were never set or filled out.

For example, if the user had filled out only these inputs and then submitted the form, it would return an error for inputs `custom_2` to `custom_9`. Why and how can I fix this?

```
<input name="custom_0" type="text" placeholder="Fill this out...">
<input name="custom_1" type="text" placeholder="Fill this out...">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actually, the issue is to what extent you will perform custom_$i checks ... since the dimension of your input is dynamic, you should rethink the code and send POST data as an array and iterate over it using foreach

the template for generating your input fields should be

```
<input name="custom[0]" type="text" placeholder="Fill this out...">
<input name="custom[1]" type="text" placeholder="Fill this out...">
```

then accessing the data is simply done with foreach or for starting from 0 to length of array ... but foreach is better

```
foreach($_POST['custom'] as $stuff){}
```

you can test incoming data with `print_r($_POST);` to see the underlying data structure

mind you that with this approach you can't get the index where **$stuff** belongs to, so using **array_keys($stuff)** allows you to access the element as **$_POST['custom'][$stuff]** and access your error array using **$errors[$stuff]**

another approach for looping over your array is

```
foreach($_POST['custom'] as $key=>$value)
```

and access $key and $value separately , thus handling the issue described above

reference at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183914/how-do-i-get-the-key-values-from-post

Comment: I don't know any better approach for this kind of dynamic form

Comment: if the key is numeric, one could struggle with while or for loops, but if the keys are words ... like custom["name"] or custom["age"] ... foreach is like a swiss army knife

Comment: What values would $stuff be?

Comment: if custom[0] held "FGSFDS", then $stuff = "FGSFDS", depends on the iteration, custom[1] could be empty and custom[2] could have "MOO" , you check if $stuff == "" and register an error ... mind you that with this approach you can't get the index where $stuff belongs to, so using array_keys($stuff) allows you to access the element as $_POST['custom'][$stuff] and do something like $errors[$stuff]

Comment: also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183914/how-do-i-get-the-key-values-from-post is relevant

Comment: And if I were to use words like `custom['age']`, how would I access that specific value in the loop?

Comment: bad timing, my last two comments answer your last question

Comment: Yeah, I just got that. :P

Comment: another approach would be foreach($_POST['custom'] as $key=>$value) and access $key and $value separately... use what's best for you

Comment: i've updated my answer with all important details, let us know if any other issues arise

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're checking against all possible inputs in your PHP (in this case 10):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
    if(isset($_POST["custom_$i"])) {
...
```

What you should do is pass in the numbers you'd like to check against, not the total, and then only validate those on the PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $errors = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        if(isset($_POST["custom_".$i])) {
            // input is set, continue verification code...
        } else {
            $errors["custom_".$i] = "ERROR!";
        }
    }

    // code to echo back errors

?>
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything.

Comment: "custom_".$i is not "custom_$i"

Answer (score 0):

Your inputs will still be set although they don't have a value.

Instead of this:

```
if(isset($_POST["custom_$i"]))
```

do this

```
if(isset($_POST["custom_$i"]) && $_POST["custom_$i"] != "")
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

you better code your php like bellow

```
<?php

foreach($_POST as $cus){

if(!empty($cus))[

// the input is not empty


} else {

//the input is empty
}



}
```

and your inputs are set whether they are full or empty .

you are suggested to use `if(!empty($_POST["custom_$i"]))` in your own code