# Limited Foreach?

Tags: php, foreach

I'm looking for a way to only put a few varibles in a foreach loop.

Basically, I'm looking for nulls, and using die to tell the user to go back and fill in the form.

This is my array:

```
$posted = array(
$sales_rep = strtoupper($_POST['sales_rep']),
$c_first_name = strtoupper($_POST['c_first_name']),
$c_last_name = strtoupper($_POST['c_last_name']),
$c_address = strtoupper($_POST['c_address']),
$c_zip = strtoupper($_POST['c_zip']),
$deal_number = strtoupper($_POST['deal_number']),
$deal_stock_number = strtoupper($_POST['deal_stock_number']),
$deal_selling_model = strtoupper($_POST['deal_selling_model']),
$deal_trade_in_model_1 = strtoupper($_POST['deal_trade_in_model_1']),
$deal_trade_in_amount_1 = strtoupper($_POST['deal_trade_in_amount_1']),
$deal_trade_in_model_2 = strtoupper($_POST['deal_trade_in_model_2']),
$deal_trade_in_amount_2 = strtoupper($_POST['deal_trade_in_amount_2']),
$deal_new_status = strtoupper($_POST['deal_new_status']),
$deal_dh = strtoupper($_POST['deal_dh']),
$deal_finance_amount = strtoupper($_POST['deal_finance_amount']),
$deal_pack = strtoupper($_POST['deal_pack']),
$deal_retro = strtoupper($_POST['deal_retro']),
$deal_holdback = strtoupper($_POST['deal_holdback']),
$deal_reserve_amount = strtoupper($_POST['deal_reserve_amount']),
$deal_warrantee = strtoupper($_POST['deal_warrantee']),
$deal_gap = strtoupper($_POST['deal_gap']),
$deal_etch = strtoupper($_POST['deal_etch']),
$deal_maintenence = strtoupper($_POST['deal_maintenence']),
$deal_gross = strtoupper($_POST['deal_gross'])
);
```

These last few can't go in, however, because they're hidden from the form unless the user says so (they can be null):

```
$deal_reserve_amount = strtoupper($_POST['deal_reserve_amount']),
$deal_warrantee = strtoupper($_POST['deal_warrantee']),
$deal_gap = strtoupper($_POST['deal_gap']),
$deal_etch = strtoupper($_POST['deal_etch']),
$deal_maintenence = strtoupper($_POST['deal_maintenence']),
$deal_gross = strtoupper($_POST['deal_gross'])
```

I'm aware that there is maybe a way to do this with if, but I'm trying to avoid cluttering my code, and I'm looking for a really neat way to do this, maybe in the foreach itself.

**My question: Is it possible to say, in the foreach statement, to only put in a couple of varibles?**  (To restrict the ones I've set aside at the very end of the array)

If this doesn't work, I will likely run a Javascript function to fill these values to actually say something along the lines of "NULL," but odiously that's not the most efficient way to do that.

Comment: So what is the question now? Do you want NOT to go through these array elements?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/184104/460557

Comment: tip: `$case_changed = array_map ('strtoupper', $_POST);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a pretty easy way of doing it...

```
$v_info = array(  // V being visible
$sales_rep = strtoupper($_POST['sales_rep']),
$c_first_name = strtoupper($_POST['c_first_name']),
$c_last_name = strtoupper($_POST['c_last_name']),
$c_address = strtoupper($_POST['c_address']),
$c_zip = strtoupper($_POST['c_zip']),
$deal_number = strtoupper($_POST['deal_number']),
$deal_stock_number = strtoupper($_POST['deal_stock_number']),
$deal_selling_model = strtoupper($_POST['deal_selling_model']),
$deal_trade_in_model_1 = strtoupper($_POST['deal_trade_in_model_1']),
$deal_trade_in_amount_1 = strtoupper($_POST['deal_trade_in_amount_1']),
$deal_trade_in_model_2 = strtoupper($_POST['deal_trade_in_model_2']),
$deal_trade_in_amount_2 = strtoupper($_POST['deal_trade_in_amount_2']),
$deal_new_status = strtoupper($_POST['deal_new_status']),
$deal_dh = strtoupper($_POST['deal_dh']),
$deal_finance_amount = strtoupper($_POST['deal_finance_amount']),
$deal_pack = strtoupper($_POST['deal_pack']),
$deal_retro = strtoupper($_POST['deal_retro']),
$deal_holdback = strtoupper($_POST['deal_holdback'])
);
$nv_info = array( // NV being not visible
$deal_reserve_amount = strtoupper($_POST['deal_reserve_amount']),
$deal_warrantee = strtoupper($_POST['deal_warrantee']),
$deal_gap = strtoupper($_POST['deal_gap']),
$deal_etch = strtoupper($_POST['deal_etch']),
$deal_maintenence = strtoupper($_POST['deal_maintenence']),
$deal_gross = strtoupper($_POST['deal_gross'])
);
foreach ($v_info as $raw) {
if ($raw == null) {
    die("Please fill in all the required elements in the form. ");
}
}
$merged_arrays = array_merge($v_info, $nv_info);
```

This works best because I plan on putting this into a database, and for consistency I desire it all to come from one array.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of hidden keys:

```
$hidden = array('deal_maintenence', 'deal_gross');
```

You can then iterate through the `$_POST` array and check if the key is a hidden key or not:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if (!in_array($key, $hidden)) {
        if (!empty($_POST[$key])) {
            // valid
        } else {
            // invalid
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can do it the other way by specifying the keys you want to validate:

```
$keys = array('sales_rep', 'c_first_name', 'c_last_name');

foreach ($keys as $key) {
    if (isset($_POST[$key]) && !empty($_POST[$key])) {
        // valid
    } else {
        // invalid
    }
}
```

Comment: So does that mean that no, it is not possible to simply say in the foreach statement that you only want to use $posted[0-x] as $raw??

Comment: `$_POST` is an associative array. You need to specify either the keys you want to validate, or the ones you don't want to validate. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like this:

```
$variables = array ("c_first_name", "c_last_name" /* etc. */);
foreach ($variables as $v)
{
    if (isset ($_POST[$v]))
    {
        $posted[] = $$v = $_POST[$v];
    }
    else
    {
        // scold the user for not having set the variable
    }
}
```

This being said, I would rather encapsulate the form in a PHP class to avoid creating a bunch of variables.